# Safari doesn't recognize my media query speciacally for Ipad Pro

Tags: ipad, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to make the Ipad Pro resposnsive.  It all looks normal on the mobile emulator but wehen I test the Ipad on Xcode, the background is completely wrong.  When I look in Chrome, it is using the media queries properly but in safari, it doesn't even acknowledge it for the Ipad Pro.  Here is my code:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

@media only screen 
and (min-width: 1366px)
and (max-width: 1366px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 1366px)
and (max-width: 1366px)
and (orientation: landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)  { /* changed to 1.5*/
    
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 1024px) 
  and (max-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  **and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)** { /* changed to 1.5*/
   
  }
```